# I need to reset my password but never receive an email

Tags: password-recovery

I have clicked on the link for "Forgotten Password" but I never receive an email with the link to reset the password. I have checked my junk folder but nothing gets sent to me. Is there another way to get a new password for the back office? The email address on Magento is correct.

Comment: you need a new password for the user or an admin account?

Comment: What Version? Where are you doing your reset from? Did it suddenly start or has it always happened? Do you transactional emails work? Did you recently upgrade?

Comment: don't have enough reputation to comment, but I just wanted to say that Marius solution worked for me Magento 1.7.0.2, thank you.  comment  by`lazy_coder"

Answer (score 2):

If you have shell (ssh) access to your installation you could use n98-magerun (see https://github.com/netz98/n98-magerun#installation how to install magerun) to reset the password. After installation use the following command to reset the admin password:

```
[path to/]n98-magerun.phar admin:user:change-password [username]
```

Then enter the new password, after this you should be able to login again.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a solution for getting a new password, but I can offer you one to create a new admin account via code. Then you can use that to change the password to your main account or you can adapt it to change your password instead of creating a new admin user.

create a new file called `adminuser.php` on the same level as `index.php` with this content

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

umask(0);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage::getModel('core/store')->load(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID));
$username = 'yourUsername';//desired username
$firstname = "Firstname";//desired firstname
$lastname = "Lastname";//desired lastname
$email = "email@example.com";//desired email
$pass = 'yourPaSSWordHere';//desired password
$user = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->load($username, 'username');
if ($user->getId()){
    echo "User {$username} already exists";
    exit;
}
$user->setUsername($username)
     ->setFirstname($firstname)
     ->setLastname($lastname)
     ->setEmail($email)
     ->setPassword($pass)
     ;
$result = $user->validate();
if (is_array($result)){
    foreach ($result as $res){
        echo $res."\n";
    }
    exit;
}
try{
    $user->setForceNewPassword(true);
    $user->save();
    $user->setRoleIds(array(1))->saveRelations();
    echo "User {$username} was created";
    exit;
}
catch (Exception $e){
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

then just call in the browser `MAGENTO_ROOT/adminuser.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you've just the wrong e-mail address registered in the database for that account. Or wrong e-mail settings for your store(than no mail can be send at all)

If you have database access by phpmyadmin or a similar tool you could change the password by reseting it manually.

Goto the table `admin_user` and edit your user, save the password in md5('new password') en viola you can use the new password.